# Selenium - Cannot Start Firefox

Tags: php, selenium, yii

I'm learning Selenium using Netbeans as my IDE and Yii Framework.

When I tried to run my test file, it shows this error:

```
Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at 'http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/': Failed to start new browser session: org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException: Error while launching browser
/srv/http/yii-1.1.14/test/CWebTestCase.php:64
```

This is my configuration files:

**bootstrap.php**

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yiit=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../yii-1.1.14/yiit.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/test.php';

require_once($yiit);
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/WebTestCase.php');

Yii::createWebApplication($config);
```

**phpunit.xml**:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
        colors="false"
        convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
        convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
        convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
        stopOnFailure="false">

    <selenium>
        <browser name="Firefox" browser="*firefox /usr/bin/firefox" />
    </selenium>

</phpunit>
```

**WebTestCase.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Change the following URL based on your server configuration
 * Make sure the URL ends with a slash so that we can use relative URLs in test cases
 */
define('TEST_BASE_URL','http://photogallery.lan/index-test.php/');

/**
 * The base class for functional test cases.
 * In this class, we set the base URL for the test application.
 * We also provide some common methods to be used by concrete test classes.
 */
class WebTestCase extends CWebTestCase
{
    /**
     * Sets up before each test method runs.
     * This mainly sets the base URL for the test application.
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->setBrowserUrl(TEST_BASE_URL);
    }
}
```

My standalone Selenium Server version is 2.39, please guide me, thanks.

Comment: is `/usr/bin/firefox` existant, and have proper execution privs?

Comment: yes, it's executable, I've tried to run it from terminal

Comment: I may be wrong but it looks like you're running a `RemoteDriver`? Have you ensured that the `selenium-standalone-server*version-here.jar` is running when you try to launch your test?

Comment: yes, I've run it using this command `sudo java -jar ~/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar`

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087143/invalid-response-while-accessing-the-selenium-server

Comment: @AliMasudianPour seems like this is what I'm experiencing right now, thanks for the reference, I'll try the given solution, thanks

Comment: hi @AliMasudianPour, I've tried to run the test via this command `phpunit   --bootstrap bootstrap.php -c phpunit.xml functional/SiteTest.php `, but I'm still getting this error, can u please tell me what should I try to do next ?